# How to use tab in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, tabs

I am trying to create a tab in angular 6 but when the app first loads all the tabs are visible and the links do not work.

```
<div ng-init="tab=1">
    <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 1">
      <a [routerLink]='["/search"]' (click)='collapse()'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span> Search
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 2">
      <a [routerLink]='["/"]' (click)='collapse()'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
      </a>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="tab == 1">
      <app-search-component></app-search-component>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="tab == 2">
      <p>secondb</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you’re trying to use AngularJS (1) stuff in Angular (6). Watch out for that when looking up resources.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks, I have been researching how to make tabs in angular 6 but I have not come across one yet, if anyone has a link to a angular 6 tutorial I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic tabs example written in angular 4+ and angular material library (version 2):

tabs.html:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="tabs">
  <a mat-tab-link  class="tab"
     *ngFor="let link of routeLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.link"
     [active]="activeLinkIndex == link.index"
     >
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

tabs.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { Router } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
      selector    : 'tabs',
      templateUrl : './tabs.component.html',
      styleUrls   : ['./tabs.component.scss']
    })
    export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

      routeLinks: any[];
      activeLinkIndex = -1;

      constructor(
        private router : Router
      ){
        this.routeLinks = [
          {
            label  : 'Tab 1',
            link   : './tab-1-link',
            index  : 0
          },
          {
             label  : 'Tab 2',
            link   : './tab-2-link',
            index  : 1
          },
          {
              label  : 'Tab 3',
            link   : './tab-3-link',
            index  : 2
          }
        ];
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.activeLinkIndex = this._markingTabLogic(this.router);

        this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
//A bit generic url matching
//this.activeLinkIndex =this.routeLinks.indexOf(this.routeLinks.find(tab => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));

//A more fine grain matching
          this.activeLinkIndex = this._markingTabLogic(this.router);
        });
      }

      _markingTabLogic(router){
        if(router.url.indexOf('tab-3-link') > -1){
          return 2;
        }
        else if(router.url.indexOf('tab-2-link') > -1){
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }

    }
```

also don't forget to import angular material in your components module (the module of your tabs component):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MatTabsModule}    from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {TabsComponent} from "./tabs/tabs.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,RouterModule,MatTabsModule]
  declarations: [TabsComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

If you need a tutorial - check this:
https://www.nikhildevre.com/creating-tabs-using-angular-material-5-and-angular-5-routing/

Comment: I have tried but I am getting this error `Can't bind to 'active' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.` Google it and they said to import router buts its already imported from what you have.

Comment: what angular version you use?

Comment: plus i've edit the answer to include angular material tabs.

Comment: I am using Angular 6

Comment: I found that there was "]," Missing in the edit, I am new to the framework and I can't get the tabs to display visible, If you know of any useful tutorials on tabs in angular 6 that would be much appreciated. Everything I tried from what Ive learnt about the framework when implementing the tabs to my exiting project I am getting a 404 `error cannot get`

Comment: Fixed the "[". There are many tutorials, but i summarised it to the example above - can you tell me what is not working for you in the simple code i've added above?

Comment: Anyway, i've added a reference for you in the answer. tell me if its what you looked for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177409/discussion-between-rotemya-and-decoder94).

Comment: I found the solution to my problem [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11100#issuecomment-387572824)