# How to create payment form using multiple tabs

Tags: html, css, angular6

There are three tabs each containing a form. And the next tab only active when the previous tab form is valid. I want to include the next and previous button in each tab. how to achieve it?

Comment: Hi Mukesh, welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, your question doesn't contain enough information for us to help you very much. See [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for some information on how to ask *great* questions that will get you awesome answers. Specifically, we'd like to see some actual code and all the work you've already put towards trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Bootstrap Tabs may help you: https://codepen.io/techiegang/pen/QjdgJJ

Comment: Maybe helpful [How to use tab in angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683030/how-to-use-tab-in-angular-6)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Wizard Form for this purpose see the link below
[Wizard Form](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)